# MacBook 16 camera does not return 720p video stream in browsers

Tags: video, resolution, camera

Stumbled on this accidentally. It seems surprising  Macbook 16-inch camera can't provide a 720p video stream.

I used this website https://webrtchacks.github.io/WebRTC-Camera-Resolution/ to scan what my camera can do and the best the cam does is 640x480.

[image: Macbook Pro 16 inch camera supported modes]

That does not seem right to me since the [specs](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/specs/) list a 720p camera.

[image]

The question I have is ... what am I missing to make 720p camera work as 720p?

PS: Macbook Pro 13 inch camera actually seems to support 720p. o_O

[image: Macbook Pro 13 inch camera can do 720p]

Comment: You haven't told us precisely which Macbook you have.

Comment: That does not really important since it's been pretty much one generation of MB Pro 16 inch. Here is exactly what I have MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)

Comment: But that requires us to already know that… adding the information to your actual question would be useful for anyone trying to help, who doesn't already own that model.

Comment: It’s important, as what web browser and version you use and sometimes the exact build number of MacOS and possibly firmware details in the future... :)